# How would you say 悲凉 in English?

Tags: translation

How would you say 悲凉 in English? For example,

> 每当想起自己的经历，心里就阵阵悲凉。

Comment: T.L. welcome to Chinese Language and Usage. :) In the future, please remember to provide some research effort when you ask for translations, as stated by our [FAQ]. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

悲 means sad and 凉 means cold. So you feel both sad and cold. You can translate it as desolate or dismal.

Some definitions from different dictionaries:

- According to 《现代汉语规范词典》 悲凄  is **悲伤+凄凉** and 悲伤 means sad, sorrowful and 凄凉 means desolate, cold and lonely.
- According to 《现代汉语词典》 悲凄 is **悲哀+凄凉** and 悲哀 means grieved, sorrowful, sad and 凄凉 means desolate, cold and lonely.
- *Comprehensive Chinese-English Dictionary* has **sad and cold**
- [*MDBG*](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E6%82%B2%E5%87%89) has **sorrowful, dismal**

I would translate your sentence as *Every time he recalled his own experiences, he felt sad and cold in his heart for a while*.

Comment: 悲凉 => 悲惨，凄凉. So I think it should also represent "miserable".

Comment: According to 《现代汉语规范词典》 悲 refers to 悲伤 and according to 《现代汉语词典》 it refers to 悲哀.

Comment: Miserable and desolate can be used interchangeably *in some cases* to refer to a state of extreme sadness. **Forlorn** would be another word that fits the criteria. To me 悲凉 and 凄凉 are synonyms. It's essentially splitting up the word 悲凄 (sad) and combining each with 凉 (cold).

Answer (score -1):

"He shivered at the memory." ?

Comment: The listener is more interested in a general English translation of the word 悲凉. Probably not generally translated as a verb such as "shiver"

Comment: OK. My intention was to convey the meaning, not the pronunciation. I thought maybe the quotation marks would get this intention across. 
bēi liáng seems to me the sort of feeling you'd have while shivering at some bad memory.